# will record or will be recorded

Tags: grammaticality, passive-voice

Which one is correct?

I also checked the National Library which any official translation will record in it.

or

I also checked the National Library which any official translation will be recorded in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are wrong.

You don't need both "which" and "it":

- "I also checked the National Library, which any official translation will be recorded in."

Notes:

1. You need the comma, as the clause adds extra description to National Library, and does not serve to specify "which National Library?" The implication is that there is only one such, and so any extra clause serves only to add more information to what has already been identified.
2. The location where the record is being held has already been identified by the pronoun "which", and so there is no need to add another pronoun "it".
3. "be recorded", as it is the passive voice which is needed here.

It can also be argued that because "it is wrong to end a sentence with a preposition" (a contentious statement) it would be better as:

- "I also checked the National Library, in which any official translation will be recorded."

Answer (score 0):

Neither of these are correct. You can't use "which" like that. I would say:

> I also checked the National Library where any official translation will be recorded.

Comment: You also need a comma. See my own answer.